# JBOSS create PDF, XLS

Tags: excel, pdf, jboss, struts2, xls

I am writing a JBOSS web app with Struts2 and would like to produce reports in PDF and XLS format. How can I do this? Are there popular packages that can do this for me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331667/design-of-reporting-services-for-java-webapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a list](http://java-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries) of PDF libraries for Java.  We use iText extensively.

[jFreeReport](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) (scroll down on linked page to find) also offers Excel generation, though I have not used that.